# set a minimum number of bones to the vertices?

Tags: bones

Is there a way to set a minimum number of bones to the vertices? Supposed there are three bones in the scene, and I want the vertices to have at least have two bones attached to them.

Comment: Can anyone help me or is the problem impossible to solve?

Comment: I dont quite understand your question. Could you be a bit more specific about what you are trying to achieve, and maybe some pictures?